# get Path from xml-files (Python)

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have 300 XML files, in each file there is a path (see code) and i want to make a list (.CSV) of this Paths with Python.

```
 <da:AdminData>
    <da:Datax />
    <da:DataID>223</da:DataID>
    <da:Date>2013-08-19</da:Date>
    <da:Time>13:27:25</da:Time>
    <da:Modification>2013-08-19</da:Modification>
    <da:ModificationTime>13:27:25</da:ModificationTime>
    **<da:Path>D:\08\06\xxx-aaa_20130806_111339.dat</da:Path>**
    <da:ID>xxx-5225-fff</da:ID>
```

I wrote the following code, but does not work for **subdirectories**

```
import os, glob, re, time, shutil

xmlpath = r'D:'

outfilename = "result.csv"


list = glob.glob(os.path.join(xmlpath,'*.xml'))




output = ""

for file in list :

    fh = open(file)
    text = fh.read()
    pattern = "<da:Path>(.*)</da:Path>"
    pattern = re.compile(pattern);
    a = pattern.search(text)

    if  a:
        output += '\n' + a.group(1)




logfile = open(outfile, "w")
logfile.write(output)
logfile.close()
```

Comment: You shouldn't use regexp to parse xml. Use proper xml parser instead. How does sample entry with subdirectory look like?

Answer (score 0):

To glob recursively, it is best to use a combination of `os.walk` and `fnmatch.fnmatch`. Example:

```
import os
import fnmatch


def recursive_glob(rootdir, pattern):
    matching_files = []
    for d, _, fnames in os.walk(rootdir):
        matching_files.extend(
            os.path.join(d, fname) for fname in fnames
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(fname, pattern)
        )
    return matching_files


xmlfiles = recursive_glob(r"D:\", "*.xml")
```

Comment: I get an empty list :(